# How to open form from module (referenced project)

Tags: vb.net, module

I have 3x projects in my solution and one project as MDI container to open forms inside this form.
I use this code to open forms:

```
Dim form1 As New Purchasing.POlist
    Foform1.MdiParent = Me
    Foform1.Show()
```

It worked well, but I added a new project to my solution. That project is started from a Module or without application framework.

Question: How can I open that kind of project in my solution, as MDI Child?
if I use the code above it only let me choose forms, or classes inside that project and not a Module to start it.

Comment: Nothing changes. You specify the type you want to create an instance of, you assign the parent for to its `MdiParent` property and then you call `Show`.  It's exactly the same regardless of where you call it form.  Do you have any trouble using all the types from the .NET Framework class library in your projects, even though thewy are not declared there?  Of course not.  The only thing you would need to change in that code is how you refer to the parent form.  If the code is not actually in the parent then obviously `Me` doesn't refer to the parent form, so use a variable that does.

Comment: how can i use a variable that refer to parent form? i want to use parent form to open another form in another project,,but that project start from a module,without application framework..

Comment: How do you use a variable to refer to anything?  You assign the thing to the variable.  You must be opening the parent form in the first place so assign it to a variable.  Stop[ trying to make it hard.  You know how variables work.  You're assigning a form to one in the code you posted.  Why would it be any different for a different form?

Comment: when i open that project as standalone solution (without any other projects) from module,,its work well..but when i change to application framework,,and choose startup form..im getting a error.when i change back to start without application framework and without start up form ( module as start up) its work again.. Besides,,i need to reference this project to my MDI project..i need to start up from a module,cos if start from form,,its not work

Comment: In another words,,im trying to open form inside MDI..that project starts from module,,and i dont know how to add a variable to open it from module

Comment: So you have a solution with three projects, from the start up project, you want to open a console application in another project, right?

Comment: to be honest,,im not sure is it console application or not,,but all i know its start from module and dont use application framework (in project properties).. this form i wish to open within another project which is MDI.i use code i posted before,,but its not work..its not open corectly,becsuse in code before i can choose  forms,not module.

Comment: i have 3 projects,,one of them is project which i try to open in MDI parent form..

Comment: i dont think its console application,,cos its like windows form,,just dont use application framework..snd start from module

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `ME` as the parent container because youre assigning the module as your parent container which you cannot do...
Try this :

```
'this block of code below is from module
public sub openForm1()
    Dim form1 As New Purchasing
    form1 .MdiParent = frm_Main_Menu 'your parent container here
    form1 .Show()
end sub

'this code below is from form
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    openForm1()
End Sub
```